# How to configure mouse actions on a linux system?

Tags: linux, mouse, thinkpad, google-chrome-os, trackpoint

If the question sounded simple, let me specify: I'm using Chrome OS, which is a heavily modified Gentoo distribution, but I have dev mode enabled so i am able to do most things, and in theory everything in commandline that linux should be capable of.
Now the second specificity is that i am addicted to thinkpad trackpoint mouses (or nipples, as you may know them), so i got a lenovo bluetooth keyboard with one (and without a trackpad https://linkgear.jp/uploads/IMG_1361.jpg ).
But: out of the three mouse buttons, chrome os doesn't seem to support the middle mouse triggering the scrolling action to scroll by holding that+moving the trackpoint, therefore i am simply left without scrolling ability.
This limits my performance by like 50%, as opposed to the 25% that my annoyance with trackpads take away in comparison.

Now I haven't been convinved that Chrome OS is incapable of receiving this scrolling mouse action, nor would i easily believe it because it's literally just yetanother linux at core.

I am open to any hacking idea someone might have, but i couldn't find much so far about the mouse interfaces of chrome os or it's certain "Ash" window manager.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First use `evemu-record` to verify what raw physical events arrive (or maybe `libinput debug-events` to see similar, but libinput-processed events).

Assuming they do, you should be able to build something out of [interception-tools](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools) to alter those events in-flight – something very similar to the "x2y" example in the project's README, but changing the [event code](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2016/09/understanding-evdev.html) from `REL_Y` to `REL_WHEEL` if the button is currently pressed.

```c
bool held = false;
while (..) {
  if (event.type == EV_KEY && event.code == BTN_MIDDLE) {
    held = (bool) event.value;
  } else if (held && event.type == EV_REL && event.code == REL_X) {
    event.code = REL_WHEEL;
  }
  ..
}
```

Comment: this seems like it will work, evemu-record said this on middle mouse: 

chronos@localhost /usr/local/src/evemu $ ./tools/evemu-record 
Available devices:
/dev/input/event14:     ThinkPad Keyboard Keyboard
/dev/input/event15:     ThinkPad Keyboard Mouse
/dev/input/event16:     ThinkPad Keyboard
Select the device event number [0-16]: 15

Comment: (had to split for char. limit, and idk why stackoverflow removes my linebreaks...)
#      Waiting for events     #
E: 0.000001 0004 0004 589827    # EV_MSC / MSC_SCAN             589827
E: 0.000001 0001 0112 0001      # EV_KEY / BTN_MIDDLE           1
E: 0.000001 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +0ms
configure: error: in `/usr/local/src/evemu':E: 0.062792 0004 0004 589827        # EV_MSC / MSC_SCAN             589827
E: 0.062792 0001 0112 0000      # EV_KEY / BTN_MIDDLE           0
E: 0.062792 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +62ms

Comment: on the other hand:  
chronos@localhost /usr/local/src/evemu $ libinput debug-events  
Expected device added events on startup but got none.  
Maybe you don't have the right permissions?  
^C  
chronos@localhost /usr/local/src/evemu $ sudo !!  
sudo libinput debug-events  
Expected device added events on startup but got none. Maybe you don't have the right permissions?  
^C

Comment: 2 spaces aren't adding linebreaks either as the hints say below commenting.... whatever, sorry if all of this has been unreadable

Comment: this will be my first C program hell ye

Comment: Most of those formatting hints only apply to full-size posts (questions or answers). Comments on the other hand are just 1-liners.